# 日本語に違和感:質問方法

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

以下の日本語に違和感があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私なら以下のように訳します。

```
質問方法
あなたの質問はプログラミングに関係していますか?
スタックオーバーフローはあなたに、ただ意見を交換するだけでなく、
回答ができる質問をすることを期待しています。
〜省略〜
スタックオーバーフローについての質問なら、メタスタックオーバーフローに質問してください。
ヘルプセンターを参考>>
質問のしかたを参考>>
```

Answer (score 1):

keiminaさんがご指摘されている通り、ここの文章(How to Ask)はとても重要だと思います。私も英語版stackoverflowをよく利用していますが、多くの新参者の質問がこのルールに関係してdown voteされているのを毎日のように見かけます。それらのdown voteの理由の多くは「プログラミングに関係していない」とか「自分の試したコードを載せていない」というものです。

keiminaさんの和訳で素晴らしいと思います。私も冒頭部分の訳を一案書かせていただきます。

```
質問方法
あなたの質問はプログラミングに関するものですか？
当サイトでは、意見交換のための質問ではなく、回答可能なプログラミングの質問をお願いします。
```

以上、ご参考になれば幸いです。